# In Kate text editor, how to open new files in new windows by default?

Tags: linux, window, editor, kate

I find terribly confusing to work with different files grouped in the same window: my mind needs to actually see *different files* floating in *different windows*.

I know that I can have multiple Kate windows open, and show different files in each window. But it seems that Kate by default opens files in the same window so that each window must "contain" all the open files, and I find it very confusing.

Is there a way to set Kate so that it behaves as I described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to launch Kate with the option -n (or --new) parameter, as explained in this page: [Kate editor behaviour](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/502871)